# How to keep different files for controller and directive which is using that controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I want to understand if there is any way that I can keep controller and directive which is using this controller in different files?
I have two files, say 1. MyController.js and 2. MyDirective.js.
When I define my directive in MyDirective.js file and inside directive I say

```
controller: 'MyController'
```

i.e. the name of the controller in MyController.js file, it says the:

```
Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider
```

When I put my directive in MyController.js file then it is able to get the controller.
Any idea why this happens and how can I maintain different files for directive and controller.

Comment: Yes, you can. Make sure that you load the controller.js file first in your html.

Comment: in your <script> tag in the html file, include both controller.js and directive.js files one by one

Comment: Thanks all for replies. @MikeFeltman - I thought of this that controller somehow is not "initialized" and directive is looking for it. But after moving directive to controller file and again separating now it is working. This is confusing that why is this working now. Will try to look further into it. Thanks for you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making the directive dependent on controller, you need to have the controller file added first:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='MyController.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='MyDirective.js'></script>
```

Comment: Yes I was doing this. But I guess the problem is related to the sequence of how the controller an directive was getting initialized.